# Django: Using CreateView in a model with a foreignkey attribute

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to use CreateView generic-class in my views.py and the model it refers to has a user attribute (which is from built-in User class in django) as foreignkey.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.urls import reverse

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**views.py**

```
from accounts.models import UserProfile
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class RegisterUserView(CreateView):
    model =  UserProfile
    fields=['username','first_name','last_name','email','password1','password2']
```

**urls.py**

```
path('register/',RegisterUserView.as_view() , name='register')
```

It's given the erros:

```
FieldError at /accounts/register/

Unknown field(s) (last_name, password1, username, email, password2, first_name) specified for UserProfile

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/
Django Version:     2.0.6
Exception Type:     FieldError
Exception Value:    

Unknown field(s) (last_name, password1, username, email, password2, first_name) specified for UserProfile

Exception Location:     /home/gaspar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in __new__, line 266
Python Executable:  /home/gaspar/anaconda3/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.6.5
Python Path:
```

My question is: the CreateView can get the data from user attribute and create a Modelform, or I have to create a custom ModelForm?

Comment: This is explicitly covered in the documentation: [models and request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create instance of `User` and then attach this instance to UserProfile `user` field.

Error is due to these fields (last_name, password1, username, email, password2, first_name) are not defined for `UserProfile`

And BTW django's `User` class does not have `password1` and `password2` attributes